# Learning GetX and Flutter and stuck with a provided example on the official site

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

here is an exception that I get while running the code down there:

**The following _TypeError was thrown building Home(dirty): type 'RxInt' is not a subtype of type '(() => void)?'**

---

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      const GetMaterialApp(
        home: Home(),
      ),
    );

class Controller extends GetxController {
  var count = 0.obs;
  increment() => count++;
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Controller c = Get.put(Controller());

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Obx(
          () => Text('{Taps: ${c.count}'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Get.to(Other()),
              child: const Text('Go to others'))),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: c.increment(), child: const Icon(Icons.add)),
    );
  }
}

class Other extends StatelessWidget {
  final Controller c = Get.find();

  Other({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('${c.count}'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

--
What's wrong with that please?

Answer (score 0):

Put the Get.put() before building the widget tree. Like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      const GetMaterialApp(
        home: Home(),
      ),
    );

class Controller extends GetxController {
  var count = 0.obs;
  increment() => count++;
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final Controller c = Get.put(Controller());
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Obx(
          () => Text('{Taps: ${c.count}'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Get.to(Other()),
              child: const Text('Go to others'))),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: c.increment(), child: const Icon(Icons.add)),
    );
  }
}

class Other extends StatelessWidget {
  final Controller c = Get.find();

  Other({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('${c.count}'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Samin. But mistake was at c.incremet(). I should have used it without void - c.increment

Comment: have you solved it?